# foreign key relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

Friend, here i have this model for member

```
class member extends Eloquent {

public $table = 'member';
public $timestamps = false;    

public function peminjaman() {
    return $this->hasMany('peminjaman', 'id_member');
}

}
```

and i have this model for peminjaman

```
class peminjaman extends Eloquent {

public $table = 'peminjaman';
public $timestamps = false;

public function member() {
    return $this->belongsTo('member', 'id_member');
}}
```

here my controller

```
function adminIndex(){        
    $list_peminjaman = peminjaman::all(); 
    return View::make('admin.peminjaman', array('list_peminjaman'=>$list_peminjaman));
}
```

then this is my view

```
<td>{{ $peminjaman->member->nama }}</td>
```

but when i run this code, this is the result

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemRental\app\views\admin\peminjaman.blade.php)

how can i fix this?

Comment: what if you try with `<td>{{ $peminjaman->nama }}</td>`? Is `nama' specified as a field in the `$peminjaman` model?

Comment: no... nama was from table member...

Comment: so you should give a try to `<td>{{ $member->nama }}</td>`

Comment: try to look the data structure `$peminjaman` on peminjaman.blade.php using `{{'<pre>'.printr($peminjaman, 1).'</pre>'}}`

Comment: when i use same code for other relation its work just fine...but for this one it wont work, i dont know what is wrong about it... T.T

Comment: Just add `null` check, for the error says, that some of your `$peminjaman` have no related `member`: `@if($peminjaman->member) {{ $peminjaman->member->nama }} @endif`